# Good non-relational/quazi-relational DB with .NET API?

Tags: .net, persistence, nosql, non-relational-database

Anyone have any recommendations for a non-relational/partially-relational DB with a .NET API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any personal experience with it, but you might check out MongoDB which has drivers in C# etc.

See this blog post for some info: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/13/experimenting-with-mongodb-from-c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just hear about [Raven DB](http://ravendb.net/) on a podcast ([Herding Code 83](http://herdingcode.com/?p=255)).  I don't know much more, but there are questions tagged [ravendb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ravendb).

> Raven is an Open Source (with a
>   commercial option) document database
>   for the .NET/Windows platform. Raven
>   offers a flexible data model design to
>   fit the needs of real world systems.
>   Raven stores schema-less JSON
>   documents, allow you to define indexes
>   using Linq queries and focus on low
>   latency and high performance.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is NPA (also called `.NET` Persistence API or NPersistence)
It is the equivalent of JAVA's JPA and offers the ability to work with POCO objects and a standard API.
The entity mapping is done using annotations (no XML needed).
see:
http://www.npersistence.org
and also:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Persistence_API